# Link GUI Created Menu to SLOT Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt Creator. I have used the "form" file `mainwindow.ui` to create menu `menuFile` with action `actionOpen`.

[image]

[image]

I have searched on google but everything I find creates the menu programmatically and links the `SLOT`s there.

How do I link the `SLOTS` from the `mainwindow.ui` file to the `mainwindow.cpp` file?

Comment: Not sure what you meant exactly, but in Qt Designer you can go in the Action Editor then right click on a listed QAction and then click on "Go to slot...". It will generate the code automatically, you just have add the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the action added in designer trough the `ui` member in your class (most likely that is a pointer, if it's an object use the the operator . to access the members), something like this:

```
//in the constuctor you connect the action with the slot
connect(ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(OpenTriggered()));

//...
//and define the slot (don't forget to declare it as a slot in the .h file)
//and replace MainWindow with your class name
void MainWindow::OpenTriggered()
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Open", "Open triggered");
}
```

And later you might need an checkable action, then you can use [toggled](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#checked-prop) signal, or [triggered(bool)](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#triggered)